# Inserting emoji through mysql workbench works but not via java?

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding, emoji

Through MySQL Workbench Queries i was able to insert an emoji into the table **but** only if i set names first.

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4; //only need to do this once everytime i start the server
insert into testtable (testfield) values (''); //works!
```

However doing the same thing in java results in an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\x96' for column 'testfield' at row 1
```

**The java:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestDao t = new TestDao();
  t.setNamesUtf8mb4(); //SET NAMES utf8mb4;
  t.insertTest(""); //doesn't work :(
}
```

**TestDao**

```
public void setNamesUtf8mb4(){
    try(Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection()){
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SET NAMES utf8mb4;");
           pst.executeUpdate();         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void insertTest(String test){
    try(Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection()){
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into testtable (testfield) values (?);");
        pst.setString(1, test);
           pst.executeUpdate(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**DBConnection:**

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static String url = null;
    private static Connection conn = null;
     public static Connection getConnection(){
     try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","1234");
     }   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
     return conn;
     }
}
```

My charset and collation for table and database

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM testtable WHERE Field = 'testfield';

+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type         | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| testfield | varchar(191) | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**my.ini:**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysql]
no-beep=
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character_set_server=utf8mb4
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

I've tried changing the connection url:

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"; //note: "=utf8mb4" isn't valid here
```

All out of ideas, any ideas why this isn't working? Why is it only working in mysql workbench and not in java? Does it have something to do with the Connector/J ?

**EDIT**

A comment suggested to set names in the same connection, which i tried and it seems to work. But isn't this terribly **inefficient**? I don't want to have to execute `set names` before every single insert or update... Surely there's a better way to do this?

**this works:**

```
public void insertTest(String test){
    try(Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection()){
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SET NAMES utf8mb4;"); //set names in same connection
               pst.executeUpdate(); 
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into testtable (testfield) values (?);");
        pst.setString(1, test);
           pst.executeUpdate(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

**sql version**

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.11    |
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT3**

JDK version of the project is `jdk1.8.0_161`

And getting hex of test() using:

```
public String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
}
```

produces:

> 000000000000000000000000000000000000003f

or getting hex of test using:

```
static String stringToHex(String string) {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(200);
  for (char ch: string.toCharArray()) {
    if (buf.length() > 0)
      buf.append(' ');
    buf.append(String.format("%04x", (int) ch));
  }
  return buf.toString();
}
```

produces:

> d83d dc96

Comment: I don't know, but I can confirm that `f0 9f 92 96` is the correct sequence of UTF-8 bytes for the character U+1F496 SPARKLING HEART, so at least it appears that the UTF-8 is reaching the database. Maybe you need to do the `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` in the ***same*** connection that is doing the insert??

Comment: thanks David, that seems to work (check my edit). But i would like to get to the heart of the problem, making an extra query each time is going to slow down my application no ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I just installed 8.0.11 and without doing anything special in the connection url or using 'set names' I am able to insert unicode including emoji with no errors. I notice you are doing `Class.forName("com.msql.jdbc.Driver")` which is the old way of setting up the connector so I guess you're using an old version?

Comment: i think i'm using the latest version, check out my second edit. Included the versioning info. What is the new way of setting up the connector?

Comment: The jar file has a `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` setting in it, so all you have to do is have the jar file in your classpath and it sets itself up. It will automatically use the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` class. If you're explicitly loading `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` it should be displaying an error message on stderr when it loads.

Comment: `Loading class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.`

Comment: that's cool, just tried it out and it does indeed work like that without the specifying the class driver. I also tested out the emoji thing again but unfortunately that didn't do the trick, still getting the incorrect string value exception

Comment: Why do you have `5.1.6` instead of `8.0.11` in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Not entirely sure, was under the impression that this was the version for something else. But i have just changed it to `8.0.11`. Restarted the server and sql server/did a clean and build of the project but the problem still persists

Comment: Well, I realize "works for me" isn't really helpful but I just want to say, I just did a fresh install of MySQL 8.0.11 because I didn't have it installed, but I wanted to try to see if I could replicate what you were seeing, and I didn't do **any** of this `character-set-client-handshake = FALSE` etc. or put anything special in my connect string, and it works out of the box. I'm wondering if some of the configuration you've done to try to make it work is now getting in the way, now that you're using the right connector? Just a guess.

Comment: Java originally used UCS-2, and added UTF-16 supplementary character support in J2SE 5.0.  What version of J2SE are you using?

Comment: Can you display `test` in hex to verify that it is `f0 9f 92 96` in the Java code.

Comment: updated question, check EDIT3, using two different ways of getting hex of test.

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem ?

Comment: I was not able to get it to work on localhost in the end, but it worked on my production server/db so i just left it at that... sorry can't help you